# Printing Odd numbers in a upside down right angle formation

Tags: java, loops

Im trying to take a number and print it's odd number like this:

```
    if i take 5 as a number it should give this: 

    1 3 5
    3 5
    5

   and if i take 9 it should do the same thing:

  1 3 5 7 9
  3 5 7 9
  5 7 9
  7 9
  9
```

This is what i have so far and i am stuck. i can't get the 5 to print after the 3 and to end it with 5 for the triangle:

```
public class first{
    static void afficher(int a){
    for(int i=1;i<=a;i++){
        if(i%2!=0){
            System.out.printf("%d",i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();

    for(int j=3;j<=a-2;j++){
        if(j%2!=0){
            System.out.printf("%d",j);
        }
    }
}




     public static void main(String[]args){
        afficher(5);


    }

}
```

This prints:

```
1 3 5
3
```

Comment: Since you are printing a "surface", you expect two nested `for`s.

Comment: a for loop within a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print a surface (2d thus), one expects that the algorithm runs in *O(n^2)* time complexity. Thus two nested `for`s:

```
public class first{
    static void afficher(int a){
        for(int i = 1; i <= a; i += 2) {
            for(int j = i; j <= a; j += 2){
                System.out.print(j);
                System.out.print(' ');
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

One can optimize the algorithm a bit by not checking `if` the number is odd, but taking steps of `2`.

See [**demo**](http://jdoodle.com/a/dK).

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is printing as follows because:

```
1 3 5 -> your i loop runs here (from 1 to 5)
3     -> your j loop runs here (from 3 to (less than OR equal to 5))
```

So I suggest the following:

1. Use 2 nested loops (for universal values):

   ```
    i running from 1 to the input number increasing by 2
    j running from i to the input number increasing by 2 also ending with line change'/n'
   ```
2. Keep a check whether the input number is odd or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use nested for-loops to resolve this problem. Go through the following code

```
public class OddNumberLoop {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner inpupt = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Input the starting number : ");
    int start = inpupt.nextInt();
    for(int i = 1 ; i <= start; i += 2){
        for(int x = i; x <= start; x += 2) System.out.print(x+ " ");
        System.out.println();
    }

 }
}
```